# Guardar usuário e senha sem uso de banco de dados

Tags: c#, arquivo, segurança, sistema-de-arquivos

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em `C#` do tipo *Console*, e estou querendo guardar algumas configurações confidenciais como usuário, senha e IP. O problema é, como guardar esses dados de forma segura localmente sem o uso de um banco de dados em qualquer lugar.

Por exemplo, no inicio pensei em guardar esses dados em um XML, mas logo vi que ficariam totalmente expostos, então pensei em criptografar, mas quando for usa-los preciso que tudo esteja descriptografados, inclusive a senha.

A questão é, como guardar esses dados em arquivo de forma segura em `C#`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, usando [Triple DES](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/3DES).

[Este artigo do CodeProject ensina como fazer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14150/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Data-with-C). Se precisar, coloco o código aqui, traduzido.

Comment: Seria bom para futuras referências e principalmente para caso o link quebre... Valeu vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Ali no artigo já está sendo aplicado o método [Triple DES](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/3DES)?

Comment: Acho difícil quebrar o link, sobretudo porque é no Code Project, mas logo edito a pergunta e coloco.

Comment: Valeu, atendeu perfeitamente.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer sem usar um banco de dados comercial, mas você irá acabar criando seu próprio "banco de dados" e todo o mecanismo para ler, escrever e proteger seu arquivo.

Você pode sim utilizar um arquivo XML e encriptografar os dados e serializar uma classe para XML e ai quando precisar utilizar você deserializa esse arquivo novamente para uma classe.

Uma forma ainda mais segura, seria ao invés de utilizar um arquivo no formato XML, utilizar um arquivo em formato binário, (.dat, .bin, .oquevocêquiser) e serializar+encriptografar no momento de salvar e deserializar/decriptografar na hora de ler.

Uma ideia fácil seria ter uma classe que já faz a criptografia no momento de salvar automaticamente e o inverso na hora de ler.
Exemplo:

```
public sealed class AccessData {
    private String _username;
    private String _password;
    private String _ipv4;

    [XmlIgnore] //Esta propriedade não irá para o arquivo .XML quando for serializada
    public String UserName {
         get { return _username; }
         set { _username = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement("UserName")] //No XML o valor será armazenado em uma tag "UserName"
    public String UserNameSecure { 
        get { return Security.Encrypt("S3Nh@S3GuR@", _username); }
        set { _username = Security.Decrypt("S3Nh@S3GuR@", value); }
    }

    [XmlIgnore] //Esta propriedade não irá para o arquivo .XML quando for serializada
    public String Password {
         get { return _password; }
         set { _password = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement("Password")] //No XML o valor será armazenado em uma tag "Password"
    public String PasswordSecure { 
        get { return Security.Encrypt("S3Nh@S3GuR@", _password); }
        set { _password = Security.Decrypt("S3Nh@S3GuR@", value); }
    }

      [XmlIgnore] //Esta propriedade não irá para o arquivo .XML quando for serializada
    public String IPV4 {
         get { return _ipv4; }
         set { _ipv4 = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement("IPAddress")] //No XML o valor será armazenado em uma tag "IPAddress"
    public String IPV4Secure { 
        get { return Security.Encrypt("S3Nh@S3GuR@", _ipv4); }
        set { _ipv4 = Security.Decrypt("S3Nh@S3GuR@", value); }
    }
}

internal static class Security {
    private const String SaltKey = "umaStringDeSalt";
    private const String ViKey = "UmaChaveQualquer";

    public static String Encrypt(String password, String value){
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);

        byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
        var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros };
        var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ViKey));

        byte[] cipherTextBytes;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                cryptoStream.Close();
            }
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
    }

    public static String Decrypt(String password, String value)
    {
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
        byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
        var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.None };

        var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ViKey));
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
        var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        var plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];

        int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount).TrimEnd("\0".ToCharArray());
    }
}
```

Note que as propriedades da classe são Username, Password e IPV4
São essas propriedades que você vai utilizar em seu código.
As propriedades UsernameSecure, PasswordSecure e IPV4Secure são apenas para utilização na serialização para XML, note que elas encriptam e decriptam os dados.

Um exemplo de uso:

```
var objeto = new AccessData();
objeto.Username = "Guilherme";
objeto.Password = "123456";
objeto.IPV4 = "192.168.1.1";   
var serializer = new SerializationHelper(); //classe que você irá criar para serializar arquivos XML.
serializer.Save("dadosDeAcesso.xml",objeto); //um método "Save" deverá salvar um objeto qualquer (objeto) em um arquivo qualquer (dadosDeAcesso.xml)
```

Como serializar uma classes para XML e para um arquivo XML

[Serializar uma classe para um arquivo XML](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm)

[Serializar uma classe para XML](http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization)

Comment: Então eu fiz algo parecido, não estou usando um `arquivo.xml`, fiz algo parecido com o que tu disse, mas não tão otimizado, sou novo no C#, não sabia que dava pra serializar uma classe para XML... :D vlw

Comment: Sim, você consegue serializar qualquer classe "publica" e suas propriedades publicas para XML, JSON ou binário. Outros formatos vocês precisar criar seu próprio "seriliazer/deserializer"